# How do you map an enum as an int value with fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Question says it all really, the default is for it to map as a `string` but I need it to map as an `int`.

I'm currently using `PersistenceModel` for setting my conventions if that makes any difference.

**Update**
Found that getting onto the latest version of the code from the trunk resolved my woes.

Comment: Food for google bots: I was getting "illegal access to loading collection" before implementing this for my enum mapping.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The way to define this convention changed sometimes ago, it's now :

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum);
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance target)
    {
        target.CustomType(target.Property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the most recent version of fluent nhibernate

Comment: This looks like it works fine for all enum types, but what if you want some as strings and some as ints?  I think this should be configurable at the property mapping level.

Comment: See the answer by @SztupY below that extends this to allow for nullable enums. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439003/how-do-you-map-an-enum-as-an-int-value-with-fluent-nhibernate/2716236#2716236

Answer (score 45):

So, as mentioned, getting the latest version of Fluent NHibernate off the trunk got me to where I needed to be. An example mapping for an enum with the latest code is:

```
Map(quote => quote.Status).CustomTypeIs(typeof(QuoteStatus));
```

The custom type forces it to be handled as an instance of the enum rather than using the `GenericEnumMapper<TEnum>`.

I'm actually considering submitting a patch to be able to change between a enum mapper that persists a string and one that persists an int as that seems like something you should be able to set as a convention.

---

This popped up on my recent activity and things have changed in the newer versions of Fluent NHibernate to make this easier.

To make all enums be mapped as integers you can now create a convention like so:

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IProperty target)
    {
        return target.PropertyType.IsEnum;
    }

    public void Apply(IProperty target)
    {
        target.CustomTypeIs(target.PropertyType);
    }

    public bool Accept(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsEnum;
    }
}
```

Then your mapping only has to be:

```
Map(quote => quote.Status);
```

You add the convention to your Fluent NHibernate mapping like so;

```
Fluently.Configure(nHibConfig)
    .Mappings(mappingConfiguration =>
    {
        mappingConfiguration.FluentMappings
            .ConventionDiscovery.AddFromAssemblyOf<EnumConvention>();
    })
    ./* other configuration */
```

Comment: with "int mode" as the default. Who persists enums as strings?!

Comment: Could be a legacy database with string values already in there

Comment: +1 hainesy. @ Andrew Bullock: answer to your question: anyone who deals with real world databases.

Comment: Is there any IProperty interface in FN?

Answer (score 40):

Don't forget about nullable enums (like `ExampleEnum? ExampleProperty`)! They need to be checked separately. This is how it's done with the new FNH style configuration:

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum ||
            (x.Property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) &&
             x.Property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsEnum)
            );
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance target)
    {
        target.CustomType(target.Property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For this addition!  First version doesn't work for the nullable enums (they remain as strings).

Comment: @SztupY The column type in the database is `int`?   And when the type accept Flags? Like: `MyEnum.Active | MyEnum.Paused`

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa: For flags check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805661/how-to-query-flags-stored-as-enum-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 25):

this is how I've mapped a enum property with an int value:

```
Map(x => x.Status).CustomType(typeof(Int32));
```

works for me!

Comment: My only qualm with this is that you have to remember to apply it to every enum. That's what the conventions were created for.

Comment: This works for reading but failed when I tried a criteria query.  Setting up a convention (see answer to this question) did work in all cases I tried though.

Comment: Well I thought it was great - but this will cause problems: see this post. http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/20/how-test-your-mappings-the-ghostbuster.aspx

Comment: @UpTheCreek It seems that this has been fixed and is now recommended by James Gregory from the NH team: http://www.mail-archive.com/fluent-nhibernate@googlegroups.com/msg01743.html

Answer (score 1):

For those using Fluent NHibernate with Automapping (and potentially an IoC container):

The `IUserTypeConvention` is as @**Julien**'s answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1706462/878612

```
public class EnumConvention : IUserTypeConvention
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Property.PropertyType.IsEnum);
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance target)
    {
        target.CustomType(target.Property.PropertyType);
    }
}
```

The Fluent NHibernate Automapping configuration could be configured like this:

```
    protected virtual ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SetupDatabase)
            .Mappings(mappingConfiguration =>
                {
                    mappingConfiguration.AutoMappings
                        .Add(CreateAutomappings);
                }
            ).BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    protected virtual IPersistenceConfigurer SetupDatabase()
    {
        return MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.UseOuterJoin()
        .ConnectionString(x => 
             x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("AppDatabase")) // In Web.config
        .ShowSql();
    }

    protected static AutoPersistenceModel CreateAutomappings()
    {
        return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<ClassInAnAssemblyToBeMapped>(
            new EntityAutomapConfiguration())
            .Conventions.Setup(c =>
                {
                    // Other IUserTypeConvention classes here
                    c.Add<EnumConvention>();
                });
    }
```

*Then the `CreateSessionFactory` can be utilized in an IoC such as Castle Windsor (using a PersistenceFacility and installer) easily. *

```
    Kernel.Register(
        Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => CreateSessionFactory()),
            Component.For<ISession>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
            .LifestylePerWebRequest() 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an NHibernate `IUserType`, and specify it using `CustomTypeIs<T>()` on the property map.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the values as int / tinyint in your DB Table. For mapping your enum you need to specify mapping correctly. Please see below mapping and enum sample,

**Mapping Class**

```
public class TransactionMap : ClassMap Transaction
{
    public TransactionMap()
    {
        //Other mappings
        .....
        //Mapping for enum
        Map(x => x.Status, "Status").CustomType();

        Table("Transaction");
    }
}
```

**Enum**

```
public enum TransactionStatus
{
   Waiting = 1,
   Processed = 2,
   RolledBack = 3,
   Blocked = 4,
   Refunded = 5,
   AlreadyProcessed = 6,
}
```